# Ontological argument and naive set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, quantifiers, modal-logic, logic-translation

When Saint Anselm argues that “God is a being that of which nothing greater can be conceived" it seems like he's expressing the following relation:

∀x (¬MorePerfectThan(x,God))

or "for all x, x is not more perfect than God." (And presumably God is not more perfect than himself.) Where x is quantifying over everything. But if x is quantifying over everything, isn't Anselm quantifying over the universal set, which renders the argument incoherent? But if he's not, how can the argument establish that genuinely nothing is greater than God?
Or does this difficulty somehow disappear when we translate the argument into modal logic rather than FOL?

(I know this question sounds like it might fit better on philosophy stack exchange. I asked it here because honestly I've found that answers to logic-related questions are always better on this site.)

Comment: Can you say more about what "quantifying over the universal set" means to you and why it might be problematic? And what is the "argument" you're referring to? (You've described a statement but not a proof.)

Comment: @Karl quantifying over the universal set is quantifying over the set which contains all objects. The objects in this set seem to be what Anselm has in mind when he states that nothing is greater than God. I think it's problematic because of difficulties pointed out about it in Russell's paradox. If you want more background on the ontological argument, skim the Stanford page. I didn't mention the full argument because it's only the premise that I mentioned that I'm concerned with here

Comment: Disclaim: there is no way to prove by logic alone the existence of something. Having said that, maybe you are right: instantiating the formula above we get: ¬MorePerfectThan(God,God). Is this reasonable?

Comment: See [Gödel's ontological proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof) for a more sophisticated attempt.

Comment: Since you mention Russel's paradox, I wonder if you're slightly confusing the notion of [domain of discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse) (the "universal set" for any first-order system) with the notion of set in a [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) (an axiomatic system that talks *about* sets using a $\in$ relation and quantifiers that range over all sets). Russel's paradox arises specifically in set theory, but the ontological argument is framed without set theory (taking the quantifiers to range over all "beings", say).

Comment: You seem to think that quantifiers can range only over sets. That restriction is indeed necessary if one wants to formalize quantificational logic within set theory.  But I don't see that such a restriction on quantification is needed in other situations, including ordinary reasoning. For example, I have no difficulty saying that everything is equal to itself.

Comment: What you have is a formal system with one relation (MorePerfectThan) and one axiom. If the term "God" is undefined, it has to be treated as a constant, but in that case the existence is automatically guaranteed in any model (because $\exists x (x = God))$ would be true in every model by definition of a model). If the term is not a constant, it has to be defined for the axiom to make sense. Good luck with that.